# JavaScript Obtain value from Given switch and write it to some file online

Tags: javascript, html

The Complete Code is shown below.
I would like to get the value of Switch and write it in some .txt file online and everytime when I'm opening this webpage,It should fetch the value from that .txt file online and update the switch accordingly.Is there any way to do it

I am a Newbie to JavaScript and all my Experience is in Python Programming.Therefore I am asking this question in a perspective of python (Python Files,Web Scraping,etc.)

Is JavaScript Capable enough of fetching some data from a file online and updating it Synchronously ?

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Dark and Day Mode</h2>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked />
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: So you are trying to create a file that will keep some kind of global state of the switch element for all users of your website?

Comment: @PeterSlaný Is there any way I can make it Local ?

Comment: @PeterSlaný Like saving some temp files in their Devices

Comment: @SimpleGuy_ take a look at [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and/or [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies), if you want to have it stored on local machine. edit: mentioned the wrong account

Comment: If you don't want to store it locally, you probably want to use either [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or the [xhr api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to fetch data from a server using ajax.

Comment: @Gunther Thanks Bro.It really Helped Me So Much

Comment: You should've posted another question instead of adding comment on this. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Gunterberg/s96hk8ua/23/) is an example of an approach you could use.

Comment: @Gunther Thanks Bro,But I wanted the images inside iframe to be of real colour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this for JS part:

```js
let isChecked = document.querySelector("#switch");
isChecked.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(isChecked.checked)
})
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Dark and Day Mode</h2>

<label class="switch">
  <input id="switch" type="checkbox" checked  />
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: When I run it in the code snippet , It's working Fine.But When I tried on my PC It's note showing result.May I Know Where should I Place the JavaScript ?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_whereto) pls